# Ctrl+Z not working in 1st control if I set 2nd control's value on change in 1st Control value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

Let's say I have an `<textarea>` control. I have bind a JavaScript function `CharCounter()` on `keyup` event to count  the number of characters in the text area. From the `CharCounter()` I am setting the number of characters left in some other label.
Now when I am in textarea and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> undo/redo is not working.

```
<div>
    <textarea id="textarea1" rows="6" cols="40"></textarea>
    <label id="label1"></label>
</div>
```

```
$("#textarea1").bind("keyup", privateMethods.CharCount);

CharCount: function () {
    var txtarea = $("#textarea1");
    $("#label1").text((1000 - txtarea.val().length) + "/" + 1000);
}
```

Comment: It's working for me, is there anything else on the textarea that might prevent certain keystrokes/modifiers (onkeydown e.g.)?

Comment: This is working fine in firefox & chrome but not in IE.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer for my question.
Just felt to share with you the following link

http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7873

It explains that IE is killing undo after any DOM mutation. 
They marked the status of this bug as "cantfix".